# Is there a universal cross-platform printer sharing protocol?

Tags: linux, windows, printing, network-printer, network-protocols

There is a printer connected to the Windows machine. The printer does not have a  Linux driver, there is only a driver for Windows (hug you all, Nvidia and printer vendors).
Is there any universal printer protocol by which a Linux "virtual printer" driver (not knowing anything about the physical printer model) can connect to a Windows machine so that a Windows driver can do the  job?

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/cross-platform-printer-sharing-in-a-nutshell-part-1-getting-started/

Comment: @Gantendo This tutorial is about setting a network printer in Linux/UNIX. I need the opposite, a network printer on Windows with Linux machine connecting to it.

Comment: Me knows, but it answers the question in the title, ya dig? Anyway, have a look at https://www.howtogeek.com/191323/how-to-share-printers-between-windows-mac-and-linux-pcs-on-a-network/ and 
https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-printing.html

Comment: A few possibilities: 1. Use Remmina to Remote Desktop from Linux to Windows to transfer and print - https://linuxkamarada.com/en/2020/04/20/remote-desktop-connection-to-windows-from-linux-using-rdp-clients/ 2. See if you can add a file remotely to the printer queue, perhaps using ideas from https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/151383-how-add-printer-send-context-menu-windows-10-a.html

Comment: You may want to reframe/elaborate.  There are standard protocols for talking with printers (lpr, socket spring to mind, and smb - windows prointer sharing).  There are also lowest-common-denominator print drivers like postscript - If you advise the printer make and model you might get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Did you try to configure Windows to "share" the printer, and then use Samba on the Linux machine to access the printer? (And no, to my knowledge there is no "universal printer protocol").